# strange string overwriting behavior in python 2.7.6 / Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm a fairly experienced programmer but new to Python.  I've been tinkering with some tutorial code for Tkinter.  This program runs and prints in a terminal, processing events on a window:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

mystring = ''

def keypress(event):
    globals()['mystring'] = globals()['mystring'] + event.char

def reveal(event):
    print mystring

def leftclick(event):
    frame.focus_set()
    print "clicked at", event.x, event.y

frame = Frame(root, width=100, height=100)
frame.bind("<Key>", keypress)
frame.bind("<Button-1>", leftclick)
frame.pack()
root.bind("<Return>", reveal)
root.mainloop()
```

So you run this in the terminal and click on the resultant window to give it the focus.  Then, each time you press a key, that letter gets added to the end of `mystring`.  When you press `<enter>`, the string you have so far is printed to the terminal.  Thus, if you type `abc<enter>`, it prints out `abc`.  So far so good.

Now, check out this sequence of events:

Input: `abcd<enter>`
Output: `abcd`

Input: `efg<enter>`
Output: `efgd`

Input: `hi<enter>`
Output: `higd`

Input: `jklmnop<enter>`
Output: `jklmnop`

Input: `qrs<enter>`
Output: `qrsmnop`

It's as though each `reveal` call resets `mystring`'s pointer to the beginning of the string, without re-initializing `mystring`.  Here's where it gets really weird: if you replace

```
root.bind("<Return>", reveal)
```

with

```
frame.bind("<Return>", reveal)
```

then the strange behavior goes away.  Any new characters get appended at the end of the string, just as you'd expect.  So somehow it's Tkinter that's doing this.

I don't really need to fix this, and I doubt anyone can explain it.  I'm just kind of tossing it up there for the benefit of the internet.  Use `frame.bind()`, I guess is the moral of the story.

Comment: What happens if you `print repr(mystring)`?  I'm guessing that your `key` handler is also getting fired for `<Return>` and you're getting a microsoft style carriage return newline combo (`'\r\n'`) -- At least, that's the only explanation that makes sense to me.

Comment: mgilson, that actually makes sense.  The string ends up with a CR in it, so the chars at the beginning of the string still exist, but they get overwritten on print.  Binding the `<Return>` event in the frame rather than in the root means the `<Return>` event is not also a `<Key>` event in the frame context, so it starts working normally (`<Key>` handler not called).  It's weird, though.  I'm running Linux.  You wouldn't think CR would be a thing.

Comment: Sure enough, binding to root and printing `repr(mystring)`, you see output along the lines of `'abc\rdef\rghij\r'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your event binding is also capturing the carriage return and appending it to `mystring`, so your data will look like "abcd\refg\rhi\r\jklmnop\rqrs\r". If you print that string to the terminal you'll see the same odd results.

If you change your `keypress` function to look like this you'll probably get the output you expect:

```
def keypress(event):
    if event.char != "\r":
        globals()['mystring'] = globals()['mystring'] + event.char
```

Comment: Thanks, Bryan.  I'm surprised this had such a sensible answer, it seemed really random because I wasn't thinking in terms of "return is also a key" and "you can't see a CR in a printed string".